# Retrieve/Update EF Entity using string representation of column - code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, ef-code-first, asp.net-web-api2

**Update**: Im trying to update an EF entity without knowing the column until run time. So I would like my front end to post to my api with a column name and its value, then have my api update the database by:

- Finding the column to be updated (using provided string)
- Update db using provided value

So given the following data inside my webapi controller:

```
string colName = 'firstName';
string colValue = 'Sam';
```

In my EF data retrieval, instead of

```
var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.firstName == colValue);  //firstName is actual column name
```

can I do something like

```
var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.'colName' == x.colValue);  //colName is the string representation of column
```

and the somehow update this give column, so something like:

```
user.colName = colValue;  //where colName = 'firstName'
```

instead of

```
user.firstName = colValue;
```

I have researched Reflection quite a bit but I'm not sure where to begin or if such a task is even possible.

I could use a loop to retrieve like data like so:

```
foreach(var x in User.GetType().GetProperties()) {
if(x.ToString() == colName)
{
var y = db.User.Where(z => z.firstName == colValue)
}}
```

Any pointers, recommendations or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Is this impossible?

Comment: What it your greater goal and why did settle on this approach? In general entity framework is meant to abstract away the details of the database so you can work with objects. This includes column names.

Comment: I'd like to update database columns one at a time, as they change on the front end. It would be nice if the front end could tell the api/EF the column to update with a given value. So I would have a controller: UpdateColumn(string colName, string colValue)... and it would decide what column needs to be updated based on the string name of the column passed in from the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, misread the question, here are the updated answer. You need to use:

```
var e = db.Entry(new User() {Id =1, Name = "test"});
var property = e.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.FirstOrDefault(p => p == colName);
e.CurrentValues[property] = colValue;
```